# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32' while using ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, razor

While loading values of a database to a list (using ToListAsync()) I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHpf4.png)

This is the model I'm using:

```cs
[Key]
public int id { get; set; }
public String password { get; set; }
```

this is the code behind (.cshtml.cs) code:

```cs
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
public PassStrengthModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}
public IList<toptenthousand> toptenthousand { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    toptenthousand = await _db.toptenthousand.ToListAsync();
}
```

Database I'm working with [screenshot of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMiEl.png) [screenshot of datatypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sxLy.png) | [github link](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/blob/master/Passwords/xato-net-10-million-passwords-10000.txt) (I've added an id column which is not present in the repo)

I can't understand the problem here,
 is it problem with db having both string and int values and me keeping the "password" var as string in the Model,
 or I'm using ToListAsync() in a wrong way?

Comment: You have type mismatch for `id` field. `id` in the model is `int` and `varchar` in the database and EF will not try to automatically convert one to another. Fix it either in the model or in the database (which is more correct approach I would say based on data)

Comment: Why is the Id `nvarchar`in the database and not integer?

Comment: yes very stupid of me, how did I not notice that *face palm*, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "Id" column in the database is nvarchar type or some sort of text type.
The function  ToListAsync()  tries to convert a string to an int, and the only int in the model is the id. So  I guess the id in the database is string type.